# How to hang mosquito net on the security bars of a window?

Tags: windows, screens

We have a long window with security bars, I've set a mosquito nets on the outer side of the bars as you can see in the images bellow.

The issue we face is that our cats (who love to spend time there watching the world) are jumping on the net (mostly when birds fly by) and they drag the nets down.

I was wondering how can I secure the nets in a way that the cat's wont be able to drag the net down. I have no access to the outer side of the window as it is the third floor so everything must be done from inside our home.

Any ideas and tricks are more than welcome!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use binder clips and a needle and thread (or just just sew it all in place if you find the binder clips aren't pinning your screen well).

Fold back the net at the top and the base so you can secure the net to the squared barracking of your security bars.

[image]

Use a needle and thread the secure the two nets to one another.

[image]

Comment: The image are broken :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and "double wrap" it at the top as you did at the bottom.
There seems to be a gap between the top bar and the wall where the netting should be able to fit through, you'll possibly only need to cut some strips out where the top bar is mounted to the wall.
Once it's been double wrapped you should be able to secure it to itself and prevent it from slipping down when the cats try to go through it.

If you're unable to do that maybe you could try mounting small diameter chicken wire fencing on the inside of the bars to help prevent your cat's nails from reaching the mosquito net.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting [tarp grips](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000SOLELW) to create positive gripping points at the tops, sides, and bottom of the mosquito netting. Then use [black plastic zip ties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FMHYOZW) to secure the netting to the bars.

That still leaves the problem of the cats climbing the netting and possibly ripping it with their claws. I would recommend yetanothercoder's idea of using [hardware cloth/small opening chicken-wire](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015PD9F52) on the inside, secured to each bar at multiple points with the zip ties. It won't be attractive but it will be functional. I have seen decorative grills at hobbyist woodwork stores that would look nicer (fancy shapes/brass coloring) but would be much more expensive than the products made from galvanized tin.